# url fetch for xgboost

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, xgboost

This is my 1st question here, and the first XGBoost try.

In colab and Spyder I tried:

```
import xgboost as xgb
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dmlc/xgboost/master/demo/data/agaricus.txt.test')
```

led to Traceback errors.

A good wish on who can let me see the correct syntax for a url fetch in python.

Comment: "Traceback errors" - what are the errors? Please include the full error message in the post

Comment: Thanks @ForceBru for considerations. One can copy>paste>run the above two lines on any IDE for details. On both colab and Spyder arises: Please compile with DMLC_USE_S3=1 to use S3